# How do I access the payload from a generic webhook in my Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a multibranch job using a generic webhook and I want to access the JSON payload the Jenkins receives. I unfortunately cannot seem to access it, I cannot define parameters for the multibranch job and I am at a loss.

I would like to determine the cause of the trigger, whether it be from a pull request, a push, a commit, etc. Multibranch pipelines don't allow for me to specify any variables in Jenkins, so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Webhook functionality is supplied by various plugins, so you need to check that specific plugin what it exposes. I.e. git plugin, subversion plugin etc. I dont think the hook-content is exposed verbatim, there might be some environment variables containing various porperties, i.e. branch name. Always an option is, to add functionality to a pluginbut it might be some work. If you have some specific use case in your mind, specifying it might help readers to find alternative solutions (not involving plugin code changes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configure a `JSONPath` variable with the JSONPath `$` and it will be resolved to the entire received JSON.

See also: https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin/blob/master/src/test/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/gwt/bdd/jsonpath.feature

And to do this in a multibranch pipeline, your pipeline can look something like this:

```
 properties([
  pipelineTriggers([
   [$class: 'GenericTrigger',
    genericVariables: [
     [key: 'everything', value: '$']
    ],
   ...
   ]
  ])
 ])
```

The [readme](https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin) has complete examples on how to use it with Multibranch.

Comment: Tomas, can you explain how to do this in a declarative pipeline, where the properties () section is not allowed?  Thank you

Comment: @Dave, I am missing the documentation for the declarative pipeline as well did you ever find it?

Comment: @Dave - I've been flailing trying to port Tomas' examples to declarative syntax. Did you ever find an answer? https://plugins.jenkins.io/generic-webhook-trigger/ looked promising, but I got a `Triggers definitions cannot have blocks` error that I haven't been able to find a solution to.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the payload by configuring build triggers in the configure section of the jenkins job.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4eXC.png)